# Layoutinflater converting for custom google marker error at bitmap

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap

I have the following codes in the first view of my fragment as follows.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_activity_fragment1, null, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textRefresh);
        customHandler = new android.os.Handler();
        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

        return view;
}
```

Next I run a timer and call a async function where in the postexecute I have the following.Here what I am doing is that I have a layout with a marker icon below and textbox on top which I need to fill dynamically.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            String s = result.trim();
            markers.clear();
            markersList.clear();
            mMap.clear();
            Log.e("onPostExecute ",result);

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "restult is"+s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String  stringSucess = "";
            //markers = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            int height = 50;
            int width = 40;
            BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.basgray);
            Bitmap b=bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
            Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            mCustomMarkerView = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
            mMarkerImageView = (ImageView) mCustomMarkerView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
           Bitmap bitmap=null;
            Marker mk = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("-34"),Double.parseDouble("151")))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getMarkerBitmapFromView(mCustomMarkerView,bitmap))));

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

}
```

I get error on this line. 
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getMarkerBitmapFromView(mCustomMarkerView,bitmap))));

The problem at times I dont know what is the error there was only one it I got this error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference but other time there is not error. Why only once but the rest there is no error and it just stopped. What could be done to resolve this issue and how to set dynamicaly the text for my inflated layout?

Below is my function for the generating bitmap image.

```
private Bitmap getMarkerBitmapFromView(View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
        mMarkerImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        Drawable drawable = view.getBackground();
        if (drawable != null)
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Here is one of custom layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialogimage2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog"
            android:text="PKH 52363"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/markerImage"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/basgray" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is how it looks on the map.

[image]

Here it how it look on the design.

[image]

Comment: post `custom_info_window.xml`

Comment: @KishoreJethava I have added my custom_infor_window.xml. I will latter have few of this with various different icon and back ground image. I will want to make them dynamic google map markers and also fill the text view dynamically too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per your layout file **custom_info_window.xml**

**it should be**

```
mMarkerImageView = (ImageView) mCustomMarkerView.findViewById(R.id.markerImage);
```

instead of

```
mMarkerImageView = (ImageView) mCustomMarkerView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
```

You are using wrong id to finding View

Comment: sorry I am a bit too new to this inflating technique I have putting some codes into test and got stucked. I like to understand further am I doing it correctly with custom marker to inflate this custom layout. I will be doing for each of my lat long point. Further how to update my text android:id="@+id/textValue" ?

Comment: @give me few minutes I dont know why my android studio keep taking long time to build on gradle each time is this norm everywhere it takes few minutes to compile?

Comment: ok now it has not error and appear but the output it totally different than what I see in the cusomt_infor_layout design?

Comment: I have added 2 images into my post to show what is shown on the map and how it looks in design view

Comment: I notice I manage to adjust the textview size and properly size it well and the image appear below the textview in the design mode. But when I run on the map the imageview never appear so there is no icon below the textview. Any reason for this

Comment: Why are you set  `mMarkerImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` in `getMarkerBitmapFromView`? remove it.

Comment: I dont get you so I should run like this Marker mk = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("-34"),Double.parseDouble("151")))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getMarkerBitmapFromView(mCustomMarkerView)))); so in the getMarkerBitmapFromView I just run it as private Bitmap getMarkerBitmapFromView(View view). Is this correct now ?

Comment: Another thing how to control the size of the final bitmap in term of height and width?

Comment: here your main problem has been solved. so post new question.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever error you are receiving, now you should follow some steps to understand and make the code working for future cases

- first: the error is on this line `mMarkerImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`
- second: you should inflate your layout in onCreateView but shouldn't initialize other views using findViewById in onCreateView because sometimes views are not properly initialized. So always use `findViewById` in `onViewCreated`(when view is fully created) Try and then let's see how it goes.
- third: check the id if you are `casting` the right view (findviewbyid..) with the right type of casting and if the variable that host it has the right type. ImageView goes with ImageView ids and not with other stuff for example.

Comment: I dont understand why at times my app just close but not error is shown so in this scenario how to capture or where can I see the error? Say if I deploy to some phone where to look for the cause of the crash?

Comment: first you mention this mMarkerImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); what is the error on this line I dont get you?

Comment: Second I cant inflate on onCreateView cause for each different lat long points in the function onPostExecute(String result)  I will have other additional logic to decide which layout to be inflated cause next I am gonna create more custom layouts for each different markers? So what is the best mechanism to achieve this dynamically?

Comment: @user5313398 you said The problem at times I dont know what is the error there was only one it I got this error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference

So you can already understand that we are talking about "setImageBitmap..."

Comment: @user5313398 Let's solve here the problem you posted, for further question flag them in new topic please

Comment: agree about the issue on setImageBitmap so what is the solution to this I am quite confuse as I took this codes based on my googling for this solution.

Comment: The first thing you should do is use findviewbyid in the onviewcreated method. See if that works, and if it has the same issue, than edit your question by adding more info. If it comes out a different error or a different approach you want to take or how to adapt your thoughts in this new approach than I am afraid it needs to be done in a new and different topic.

Comment: @I am trying kishore method seems to be working though. Only problem the icon is not appearing well